# Query to return the lookup values for multiple columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to query a legacy MySQL database and export the results as a CSV file. It is on a relatively locked-down system so the solution has to be SQL only.

The problematic table, `dbo.NGSVariantACMG`, has 23 fields each relating to a category of evidence called PVS1, PS1, PS2 etc.  Each of these fields accepts a value of `null`, '3366', '3367', '3368', or '3369', which rate the strength of the evidence in that category for each row.  These values link to human readable descriptions, 'Very Strong', 'Strong', 'Moderate', 'Supporting' respectively, which can be looked up in another table called `item`, which has become something of a dumping ground for many different lookup values.

Example of the data:

| PersonID | PVS1 | PS1 | PS2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | '3367' | ... |
| 2 | '3368' | '3366' | null | ... |
| 3 | null | '3369' | '3369' | ... |

Rather than the arbitary 4 digit string I would like to export the data in a human readable format:

| Person | PVS1 | PS1 | PS2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | 'Strong' | ... |
| 2 | 'Moderate' | 'Very Strong' | null | ... |
| 3 | null | 'Supporting' | 'Supporting' | ... |

The query I wrote below works fine, however I'm sure there is a more elegant way of doing it.  Basically, I avoid using the `item` table to look up the relevant human readable description and use a conditional CASE statement for each field:

```sql
CASE dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PVS1
    WHEN '3366' THEN 'Very Strong'
    WHEN '3367' THEN 'Strong'
    WHEN '3368' THEN 'Moderate'
    WHEN '3369' THEN 'Supporting'
END AS PVS1
```

This worked well for when I only wanted to return values for one field, but the query isn't easily scalable as I need to repeat it for each of the fields included (See example query at bottom of page which runs to over 200 lines).  Am I missing something obvious?

I have tried generating the same output using a LEFT JOIN between each field and the `item` table but this is equally verbose and less readable.  I have also tried putting the CASE statement in a function so that the query is more succinct, but I could not get my implementation to work.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

```sql
SELECT dbo.NGSVariant.NGSVariantID, dbo.NGSVariant.DateAdded, dbo.NGSVariant.ChrID, dbo.NGSVariant.Position_hg19, 
dbo.NGSVariant.ref, dbo.NGSVariant.alt, dbo.Status.Status AS 'ACMG_Class',
CASE dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PVS1
    WHEN '3366' THEN 'Very Strong'
    WHEN '3367' THEN 'Strong'
    WHEN '3368' THEN 'Moderate'
    WHEN '3369' THEN 'Supporting'
END AS PVS1,
dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PVS1_comment,
CASE dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PS1
    WHEN '3366' THEN 'Very Strong'
    WHEN '3367' THEN 'Strong'
    WHEN '3368' THEN 'Moderate'
    WHEN '3369' THEN 'Supporting'
END AS PS1,
dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PS1_comment,
CASE dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PS2
    WHEN '3366' THEN 'Very Strong'
    WHEN '3367' THEN 'Strong'
    WHEN '3368' THEN 'Moderate'
    WHEN '3369' THEN 'Supporting'
END AS PS2,
dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PS2_comment,
CASE dbo.NGSVariantACMG.PS3
    WHEN '3366' THEN 'Very Strong'
    WHEN '3367' THEN 'Strong'
    WHEN '3368' THEN 'Moderate'
    WHEN '3369' THEN 'Supporting'
END AS PS3,

# Omitted 126 lines essential repeating the above code for 18 additional fields

CASE dbo.NGSVariantACMG.BP7
    WHEN '3366' THEN 'Very Strong'
    WHEN '3367' THEN 'Strong'
    WHEN '3368' THEN 'Moderate'
    WHEN '3369' THEN 'Supporting'
END AS BP7,
dbo.NGSVariantACMG.BP7_comment
FROM dbo.NGSVariant 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Status 
ON dbo.NGSVariant.Classification = dbo.Status.StatusID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.NGSVariantACMG
ON dbo.NGSVariant.NGSVariantID = dbo.NGSVariantACMG.NGSVariantACMGID
WHERE Classification = 1202218788 OR Classification = 1202218783 OR Classification = 1202218781
```

Comment: `dbo.` means SQL Server aka MS SQL, not MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully, and re-tag if needed.

Comment: To have 23 columns of the same type is quite rare. We would usually rather choose a table with one row per person, category, and value. It is not wrong however. Using one genric lookup table on the other hand definitely is a bad idea, because it doesn't restrain you from entering invalid values. If the item table happens to contain a key/value pair 3376/doubtful, mere transposed digits could lead to PS1=doubtful for instance which probably doesn't make much sense but can cause a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow below steps, to avoid code repetition. It will make your query elegant.

1. Create scalar user defined function, which returns descriptive data for status

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetStatusDescription(@StatusID CHAR(4))  
RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS   
-- Returns the stock level for the product.  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(30);  
    SELECT @ret = CASE @StatusID
    WHEN '3366' THEN 'Very Strong'
    WHEN '3367' THEN 'Strong'
    WHEN '3368' THEN 'Moderate'
    WHEN '3369' THEN 'Supporting'
END ;  
    RETURN @ret;  
END;
```

2. Now, you need to use this scalar UDF in your SELECT Clause.

```sql
SELECT dbo.NGSVariant.NGSVariantID, dbo.NGSVariant.DateAdded, dbo.NGSVariant.ChrID, dbo.NGSVariant.Position_hg19, 
dbo.NGSVariant.ref, dbo.NGSVariant.alt, dbo.Status.Status AS 'ACMG_Class',
dbo.ufnGetStatusDescription(PVS1) AS PVS1,
dbo.ufnGetStatusDescription(PVS2) AS PVS2,
.
.
.
dbo.ufnGetStatusDescription(PVS23) AS PVS23 
FROM dbo.NGSVariant 
LEFT JOIN dbo.Status 
ON dbo.NGSVariant.Classification = dbo.Status.StatusID 
LEFT JOIN dbo.NGSVariantACMG
ON dbo.NGSVariant.NGSVariantID = dbo.NGSVariantACMG.NGSVariantACMGID
WHERE Classification = 1202218788 OR Classification = 1202218783 OR Classification = 1202218781
```

Answer (score 1):

As there is a lookup table (item), you should use it. Something along the lines of:

```
select
  personid,
  item_pvs1.value as pvs1_value,
  item_ps1.value as ps1_value,
  item_ps2.value as ps2_value,
  ...
from mytable
left join item item_pvs1 on item_pvs1.key = mytable.pvs1
left join item item_ps1 on item_ps1.key = mytable.ps1
left join item item_ps2 on item_ps2.key = mytable.ps2
...
```